# Oracle select max from multiply tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, max, union

I have this query. It doesn't work. I need to select MAX from field in 3 tables, where year = 2002. This code gives me "order_number":invalid identifier". But it's exists in tables. What's wrong. The same error with using aliases:

```
select MAX(ROUND(to_number(replace(substr(order_number,0, INSTR(a.order_number,'-')-1),'.',',')))) from(
SELECT e.order_date FROM employee_trip_orders e
where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.order_date)='2020' 
union all
SELECT p.order_date FROM postgraduate_trip_orders p
where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.order_date)='2020' 
union all
SELECT s.order_date FROM student_trip_orders s
where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.order_date)='2020' 
) a
```

Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never selected the `order_number` in the union subquery, so Oracle is telling you that this column is not available in the outer select.  Try this version:

```
SELECT MAX(ROUND(TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(SUBSTR(order_number, 0, INSTR(order_number, '-') - 1), '.', ','))))
FROM
(
    SELECT order_number FROM employee_trip_orders EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 2020 UNION ALL
    SELECT order_number FROM postgraduate_trip_orders EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 2020 UNION ALL
    SELECT order_number FROM student_trip_orders EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 2020
) t;
```